# How can I get a list of methods for xmlrpclib.ServerProxy() without using dir()?

Tags: python, methods

I can not get a list of methods on xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(). I have tried using dir(); however, the interpreter keeps returning an error.

This is what I tried:

```
>>>s = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy("http://192.168.1.72:8888")
>>>dir(s)
```

And I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1224, in __call__
 return self.__send(self.__name, args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1578, in __request
 verbose=self.__verbose
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1264, in request
 return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1297, in single_request
 return self.parse_response(response)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1473, in parse_response
 return u.close()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 793, in close
 raise Fault(**self._stack[0])

xmlrpclib.Fault: <Fault 1: '<type \'exceptions.Exception\'>:method "__dir__" is not supported'>
```

Dir() is not supported, how can I get a list of methods?

Comment: Are you after methods of the proxy object, or the methods supported by the remote system?

Comment: @Aya I'm sorry, I actually was looking for the methods I could call on the remote system.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I might be wrong, but I suspect what you're *really* after is the methods supported by the remote system which will be proxied (on-demand) to the local object.

If the server supports the XML introspection API, you can use the [`ServerProxy.system.listMethods()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xmlrpclib.html#xmlrpclib.ServerProxy.system.listMethods) method...

```
>>> s = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy("http://192.168.1.72:8888")
>>> s.system.listMethods()
```

Comment: Do you known a convenient way to accomplish this if the server does not support the introspection API?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import xmlrpclib
>>> dir (xmlrpclib.ServerProxy)
['_ServerProxy__close', '_ServerProxy__request', '__call__', '__doc__', '__getattr__', '__init__', '__module__', '__repr__', '__str__']
```

This what you're after?

According to the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir) when you pass `dir` an instance of an object, it looks for a method in that object called `__dir__` and returns the results of calling that method on the object. Since `ServerProxy` does not implement `__dir__`, you have to call it on the `class` object to get a list of it's attributes.

EDIT: Since you're actually looking for methods on the remote system this answer is now kind of useless, but I think I'll leave it here as a reference for anyone stumbling across this question.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I was actually looking for the methods I could call on the remote system. Such as "object.update_resource()"

Comment: @Brian - It's not the same as calling `dir` on an object, that would return (from the docstriing): _its attributes, its class's attributes, and recursively the attributes of its class's base classes_. The call on the class only returns a subset of what the call on the object would return. For example, it won't contain any instance attributes.